# What changed about loading Spring Resource file from classpath in Spring Boot in v1.5.12?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Prior to Spring Boot v1.5.11, the following worked for referring to a file called `auth.json` in `src/main/resources`:
`spring.cloud.gcp.credentials.location=auth.json`

Starting with v1.5.11 and continuing through into 1.5.12, the above results in a `FileNotFound` exception. But the following works:
`spring.cloud.gcp.credentials.location=classpath:auth.json`

What changed in Spring Boot 1.5.12 (or its underlying dependencies) that was responsible for this?

Comment: checking https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-gcp/docs/1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#_credentials and https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#resources if you want to specify the file from the classpath you have to specify it otherwise it depends on the underlying `ApplicationContext`; I cannot find a change listed in the documentation

Comment: What version of Spring cloud GCP are you using?

Comment: 1.0.0.M1 for <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId><artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies</artifactId>. I failed to realize that this was not specified in the spring-boot-dependencies.

Comment: There is no dependency management for Spring Cloud in Spring Boot. Can you share a sample that we can run that demonstrates that it works with 1.5.10 but does not with 1.5.11?

Comment: I am working on putting that sample together.

Comment: @StephaneNicoll I have a sanitized sample that shows this issue: https://github.com/scalderwoodsolstice/resource-loading-issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by a fix to another issue and is being tracked via another reported instance here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/12786

Practitioners hitting this behavior may either update their implementation in an appropriate way (e.g., in our sanitized sample, it would be to prefix the property with "classpath:") or to wait to see if further resolution (that doesn't regress the other fix that caused this) is possible.

h/t @Stephane-Nicoll and Andy Wilkinson.